# Is a negated positive (semi-)definite matrix always negative (semi-)definite and vice versa?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

If Matrix $A$ is positive definite.
Does it hold for every $A$ that $-A$ is negative definite?
Does the same hold for positive semidefinite $A$ too, that $-A$ is negative semidefinite?

Thank you.

Comment: Short ans: Yes.  Long ans: Welcome to MSE !  Please check the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix) and also the guidelines outlined by [How to ask a good question?](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22). Low quality questions (which do not adhere to the above guidelines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Because (for instance) $x'(-A)x = -x'Ax$, so any vector $x$ that is a witness for or against the positive definiteness of $A$ is also a witness for or against the negative definiteness of $-A$, and so on.